# Seeking a scala-esque approach to iterate through a list with access to the "next" element

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.8

I am working on a Polygon class which holds an array of vertices in an `Array[Vec2]` (with `Vec2` being a simple case class defining x and y).

Now, I would like to implement a function to return the edges of the polygon in an `Array[LineSegment]` (where LineSegment is again a simple case class which defines start and end).

The solution is to create line segments connecting each vertex to the next in the array, and finally connecting the last vertex to the first.

I'm only used to imperative programming, so this is my imperative approach:

```
def edges: Array[LineSegment] = {
  val result = new Array[LineSegment](vertices.length)

  for (i <- 0 to vertices.length - 2) {
    result.update(i, LineSegment(vertices.apply(i), vertices.apply(i + 1)))
  }
  result.update(edges.length - 1, LineSegment(vertices.head, vertices.last))

  result
}
```

This works fine, but it's plain ugly. I want to use the advantages of functional programming here, but I'm kinda stuck with that.

My idea was to put it like something similar to this:

```
def edges: Array[LineSegment] = {
    for (v <- vertices) yield 
      LineSegment(v, if (v == vertices.last) vertices.head else /* next? */)
}
```

The problem is that there's no way to access the *next* item in the array given the current item `v`.

I've read about the `sliding` method defined in `IterableLike`, however that seems to be non-rotating, ie it will not consider the first item to be subsequent to the last item and therefore not return it.

So what is a good "scala-esque" approach to this?

Comment: Can you clarify one thing: you have a polygon defined by a set of points that all lie on some plane, and they are all implicitly connected with consistent winding (i.e. in a list of [A,B,C] vertices you actually have a triangle, a cross product of (B-A) and (C-A) (normalized) yields a unit vector perpendicular to the plane). Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Note I'm working in a two-dimensional space, so we don't even have to go about its normal (unless that helps finding a solution, of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you can use `sliding`:

```
(vertices :+ vertices.head) sliding 2
```

Comment: Simply appending the first item to the end of the list, sometimes the solution is that simple... thanks a lot!

Comment: If it is a `List`, prepending will be faster, though you still have to traverse the whole list to get the last element. I think the performance will be much better, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
def cyclicSliding[A](s:Seq[A]) = s.zip(s.tail :+ s.head)

println(cyclicSliding(List(1,2,3,4)))
//--> List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,1))
```

Comment: This works exactly as I need it - thanks a lot! I will have a glance at `zip` now to understand how this works.

Comment: The "problem" of this approach is the `:+` method, which will kill performance when it is expensive to add an element at the end of the Seq (e.g. in case of List). This is also the case for Debilski's solution.

Comment: It could be worse but maybe converting it to an iterator would help in that case (and then use ‘iterator addition’ for the circular item – or, well, just add it manually…).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to (a) enumerate all (directed) edges (defined by indices to their vertices), (b) given a list of edges and a list of vertices, to construct an array of line segments (by doing lookups). Both tasks, I think, can be accomplished without mutation.

The first task (and the one you seem to be struggling with) can be dealt with as follows (in Haskell):

```
foldr (\x a -> (x,(x+1) `mod` 4):a) [] [0..3]
```

What is left is to generalize this example.

Is this what you want to do?

EDIT: added an example

Comment: Not sure to be honest, I have a little trouble translation that Haskell source to Scala... I'm new to functional programming and don't know the Haskell syntax - but I would still appreciate if you could break it down for me?

Comment: Sure (I don't know Scala so excuse me). foldr is a right-associative fold over list. The function that we pass to it is given an index x, and produces the edge (x, (x+1) % 4) where % is short for modulo operation (addition "wraps around" 4). It then conses this edge onto the resulting list of edges. So, given a list of vertex indices from 0 to 3, we compute the corresponding edges.

Comment: Aha! Yes, this would be a solution as well, using the modulo to create a cycle of sorts, thanks!

Comment: Why do people keep insisting on answering Scala questions with Haskell?  I'd understand if Scala didn't have folds, but you're not demonstrating anything that can't be done natively here.

Comment: That's a fast solution for IndexedSeq.

Comment: @Kevin: in my case, I don't know the syntax of Scala, but I know a bit of Haskell. Actually, at first I didn't want to show any code, but instead describe the reasoning behind one possible solution, maybe it would have been beneficial for some, but what's done is done.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to it with zip. This time using zipAll:

```
val l1 = List(1,2,3,4)
l1 zipAll (l1.tail,null,l1.head)
res: List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is maybe not to try to access the next element, but to keep the prevous one. So, you can adopt a `foldLeft` to your needs - get a slice of edges array without the first element, put the first element as a starting value and next something like this:

```
val n = 5
(0 to n).toList.slice(1, n + 1).foldLeft(0)((x, y) => {print(x,y); y})
```

Output:   (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5)

Comment: This would allow me to connect each vertex to the subsequent one, but the connection (5, 0) would be lacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid copying the whole list as in Debilski's solution, you can do the slightly verbose:

```
vertices.view.sliding(2).map(p => if (p.size == 1) p :+ vertices.head else p)
```

This yields a view on an iterator over a sequence of views, so don't be surprised.